# wrapping an absolute/fixed div in a relative one

Tags: php, html, css

I have an absolute positioned menu in my website over-top a div with text. I want to make sure that the text remains below the menu (similar as if it was positioned relatively)

html

```
<nav id="s-nav-wrap">

       <div id="s-nav" class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            <a href="..." id="s-logo"></a>  
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8 align-right">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

            <div id="btn-home">  <a href="...">HOME</a>  </div> 
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

css

```
#s-nav-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

#s-nav { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 150;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px; padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making it `absolute`, you are taking it out of the normal flow, no matter if it's inside a `relative` positioned element.

See [CSS reference of positioning schemes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme)

Consider instead the following options,

- making the menu part of the normal flow with `position: relative`
- setting the menu a fixed height (`height: 100px`) and giving the main content a margin with the same value (`margin-height: 100px`)